# Custom "Page not found" in Opencart

Tags: php, module, opencart

I want to add "Featured products" module in page not found template. Is there anyone who has customized "page not found" template adding some module or it's not possible?

Comment: You can load your own `404` page using `.htaccess`. I've never worked with opencart, so maybe it's not what you need.

Comment: Not really. I need to load open cart module in that page 404. If I create separate page I can't load any module :(

Answer (score 6):

Take your files like such: MVC....

**Controller:**

```
opencart/catalog/controller/error/not_found.php
```

**Template (tpl)**

```
opencart/catalog/view/theme/pikcal/template/error/not_found.tpl
```

.....you can call the view file in where ever you want now via this MVC approach

```
if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/error/not_found.tpl')) 
{
    $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/error/not_found.tpl';
}
else {
    $this->template = 'default/template/error/not_found.tpl';
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have this code in my controller/error/not_found.php file, but still no luck with showing any module

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple to achieve. Firstly, go to `SYSTEM > DESIGN > LAYOUTS` and click `INSERT`. For the layout name, put

```
Error Page
```

or something else you'll find useful to remember it by. Then in the "route" field put

```
error/not_found
```

Then save. Once that is done, simply go to your `EXTENSIONS > MODULES`, click the `EDIT` next to the module you wish to have on the page, click `Add Module` to add a new module, and from the layout dropdown of that row, choose the `Error Page` one. The rest of the settings configure as you see fit

Comment: Hi, just did this but no luck :(
I had this code in not_found.tpl: <?php echo $content_top; ?>
and added module to content top of new layout...still nothing. I just saw that I don't have folder "error" in "controller"

Comment: What version are you on? I tried that in 1.5.3.1 and it worked perfectly - http://screencast.com/t/8KHtQp3MS

Comment: My version is 1.5.1.3. I guess there may be some problem because I use custom theme. Could this be a reason?

Comment: Yeah, if you're using a custom theme, that could be the issue